# Css hover doesn't work with specific type of classes

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working on a React project and I have button that is in Link (react-router dom). So to edit the css of the button i need to add "a." before the class:

```
<Link to={'/Register'} className="btn">Sign up</Link>
```

In the css:

```
a.btn {
background-color: var(--lighter-hover-color);
color: white;
padding: 10px 25px;
margin: 15px 0;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 20px;
border: 1px solid var(--hover-color);
text-decoration: none;
```

}

So when i try to add hover function to this class:

```
a.btn :hover {
transform: scale(1.2);}
```

Nothing happens. So my question is is there any way i can make the hover to work. The problem i found is that when i have dot (.) , that makes the hover function unusable.

Comment: First, you don't need to add `a`; the class name is sufficient to match, unless you are using the `btn` class on other elements and want different classes. Secondly, remove the space between `a.btn` and `:hover` and it will work. The space is a combinator that means "match the following if it is a descendant of the current selector".

Comment: It is a type error, the pseudo selectors should go altogether with the selector. `a :hover` doesn't work. `a:hover` it works

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you can not target `Link` react component using `a` tag.

I would just get rid of `a.btn` and just use `btn:hover`.

A better and more elegant approach to style react elements is to user either `styled-components` or `css modules`.

refer this article to learn more about different ways of styling react app
https://css-tricks.com/different-ways-to-write-css-in-react/